# Translation and rotation with SetWorldTransform

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, rotation

I am trying to rotate bitmap. By invoking

```
XFORM form;
angle = -30;
form.eM11 = (FLOAT)cos(angle * 2 * M_PI / 360);
form.eM12 = (FLOAT)sin(angle * 2 * M_PI / 360);
form.eM21 = (FLOAT)-sin(angle * 2 * M_PI / 360);
form.eM22 = (FLOAT)cos(angle * 2 * M_PI / 360);
form.eDx = -SIZE / 2;
form.eDy = -SIZE / 2;
SetWorldTransform(hdc, &form);
```

The bitmap rotates around center but the rotation point is not in the middle of the hdc. If I try to add another tranformation in order to translate the bitmap right after this one then I don't see rotation effect. Is there a way to mix these transformations? Something similar to matrix multiplication should work but I have no idea how to achieve that.

Comment: You can use `ModifyWorldTransform` to multiply the existing matrix with a new one. Usually to rotate around a point you need to do -translate * rotate * +translate.

Comment: @JonathanPotter hijacking/resurrecting the dead here so I can explain what my code does: why do I need to do the two translations, do I need to do the two translations for a scale as well as a rotate, and why does negative come first in your case? (My code has negative come later...)